# How to remove space between columns in BluePrint CSS framework?

Tags: html, css, blueprint-css

I am using [blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) css framework

when using the following code:

```
 <div class="container showgrid">
      <div class="span-12">left column</div>
      <div class="span-12 last">right column</div>
 </div>
```

you will notice that there is a small space between these columns!

is there any way to remove that space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i see there is a `margin-right:10px;` attribute added on every `span-*` element in source. Try modify this value. If you want to modify only one specified div's gap, add a custom class on that one.

Comment: margin-right:0px; will remove the space between columns but it will create another space after the last column

Comment: I think it's because span-*'s width is defined also in the framework. Try to adjust them while it fits for your needs. Btw i don't know if you use webdeveloper toolbar/Chrome developer tools or any tool that can help you in the debug but i think it'd helpful now.

Comment: Thank you fabrik, the problem is solved by adding margin-right: 0px;padding-right: 10px; to the CSS of the left column, thanks god it looks awesome!, Thank you fabrik